# Loading image border is showing some white border in grey background colored div

Tags: html, css

I have a requirement like to show a loading image on a grey background colored image. But it looks weird. How to stop showing white borders to the gif image

```html
<div style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);height:500px;width:500px;">
 <img src="https://uploads.scratch.mit.edu/users/avatars/10099846.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: try this: `background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);`

Comment: @MohammadAli, no yar, i have a requirement to show  exactly background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);

Comment: actually not error in your code problem is your image border color is white so u need Photoshop to change the border color.

Comment: @MohammadAli, sorry i am not expert in photoshop. anyway i will try

Comment: ya u can change photo like photo have border  background black @GaneshPutta

Comment: The extension used in your code is .png whilst in your description you mention .gif. When I download the .png and try to open it, Photoshop tells me it is not a .png file. So you may want to try changing the extension in your source.

Comment: @Gerard, i copied that link from google, its extension shows as png, but works as gif, can u please download the image from here https://uploads.scratch.mit.edu/users/avatars/10099846.png

Comment: @GaneshPutta Same problem. I'm using Photoshop CC 2018

Comment: If you're not an expert with photoshop, you can use an online tool like this https://loading.io to create a loader gif specifying color and other details.

Comment: Is it ok for you to use filters ?

Comment: @vals Yes...! we can Use

Comment: Sorry ... I thought that I could get a solution using filters, but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: @vals...! Its Okay, anyway thank u for your effort..!

Answer (score 0):

This effect comes from the image itself, not css. Use Photoshop and in the Save for Web dialog, ensure there is no Matte color selected (on the top right side of the Save for Web window). Then the borders should disappear.